# AttributeError: 'employee' object has no attribute 'isheoverpaid'

Tags: python-3.x, attributes

---

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()
     29         def debit(deb):
     30             print('your debit is', deb.debit)
---> 31 employee('raju','bangalore',200000, 22, 1).isheoverpaid()

AttributeError: 'employee' object has no attribute 'isheoverpaid'

---

class employee:
    def **init**(self, name, city, salary, age, experience):
        self.name = name
        self.city = city
        self.salary = salary
        self.age = age 
        self.experience = experience

```
    def isheoverpaid(ip):
        if ip.experience < 5:
            if ip.experience*3*ip.experience*100000 > ip.salary:
                return 'yes'
            else:
                return 'no'
        else:
            if ip.experience*2.5*ip.experience*100000 > ip.salary:
                return 'yes'
            else:
                return 'no'
```

class bank_customer(employee):
    def _init__(self, name, city, salary, age, experience,credit,debit):
        employee.**init**(self, name, city, salary, age, experience)
        self.credit = credit
        self.debit = debit

```
    def credit(cr):
        print('your credit is', cr.credit)

    def debit(deb):
        print('your debit is', deb.debit)
```

employee('raju','bangalore',200000, 22, 1).isheoverpaid()

Comment: Your indentation is broken, which matters, especially in Python. Fix it. (Also the "he" in the method name is pointless and misleading.)

Comment: Sloved: Inline missing